# Overriding C#'s Monitor.Enter and Monitor.Exit

Tags: c#, multithreading, operator-overloading, overriding, deadlock

I'm working on some big multi threaded project, now yesterday I had a deadlock (my first one ever), and I traced it by adding a Console.WriteLine("FunctionName: Lock on VariableName") and Console.WriteLine("FunctionName: Unlocking VariableName"). Adding all those was quite some work.

First of all, the program has a main loop that runs 2 times per second, that loop pulses some other threads to complete their work after the main loop has processed. Now what happened was that I had one thread in wait state to be pulsed, when it was pulsed it called another method that'd also wait to get pulsed, but the pulse already happened, and the thread won't pulse again until the action is actually completed.

Now what I want to do is override the Monitor.Enter and Monitor.Exit functions, without wrapping them in a class.
I've heard a lot about Reflection, but I have no idea how to apply it for this purpose, I know the easiest way to achieve it all is by just using a wrapper class, but then the lock keyword won't work anymore, and I'd have to convert all locks into Monitor.Enter try { } finally { Monitor.Exit }, that's huge amount of work.

So my question: How to override the Monitor.Enter and Monitor.Exit functions, while keeping access to the base function to do the actual lock?
And if that's impossible: How to override the lock statement to call my wrapper class instead of the Monitor.Enter and Monitor.Exit functions?

**EDIT FOR CLARITY:**
I request this just for allowing me to log when the locks happen, to make the debugging process easier, that also means I don't want to create my own locking mechanism, I just want to log when a lock is *established* and when it's *released*.
The close will also not be executed most of the time, only when I come across a threading problem.

Comment: Step away from the keyboard.  Do no panic, use a brown paper bag if necessary.  You are over-reacting to an everyday threading mishap.

Comment: I know, and it probably won't happen again, but I thought that an extra monitoring option wouldn't be a bad thing.

Comment: Making complicated modifications to a simple tool in order to avoid misuse of the tool is almost always a bad idea. It's like putting a "foot recognizer" on a handgun to prevent you from shooting yourself in the foot.  In this case, you should step back and think about how you found yourself in this situation, and then remember not to do it again.

Comment: I don't want to prevent myself from shooting my own foot, I want to know when I do it.

Comment: Another point of view proving how bad&complex idea it is: have you considered that all logging introduces either extra locking and implicit synchronization (i.e. logging to console or file - that's single resource) and that may seriously skew your test case (real run that has no log and no extra sync is different than test run with log and extra syncs) - OR - when log is implemented without syncing - it will either tell you nothing (you collect/write to different pools, what was the order of events?) - OR - it will cause time recording problems (ie. was that time of event, or time of logging?)

Comment: When it comes to things like lock ordering, deadlocking, and signaling, your argument are actually not correct. Issues like deadlocks become apparent "pretty much at random", and adding extra synchronization doesn't prevent them. For things like memory safety, that'd be correct, since the extra sync could cause necessary but previously missing memory barriers to be put in place. Regardless, this was nearly 7 years ago, and you probably shouldn't be doing manual threading much in C# these days, many better alternatives :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Don't do it! That sounds bonkers ;-)**

A deadlock occurs when 2 (or more) threads are all waiting to simultaneously hold 2 (or more) locks. And each thread gets a lock and waits for the other one.

You can often redesign your code so each thread only requires a single lock - which makes deadlock impossible.

Failing that, you can make a thread give up the first lock if it can't acquire the second lock.

Comment: Yes, one thread was waiting for the other thread to pulse, while blocking the other thread, so that it couldn't pulse. The problem was caused by a change someone else made to a subclass. And finding the problem was a lot of work.

Comment: While the OP mentioned wanting this for debugging deadlocks, that's not the only situation where this would be useful. For example, we have a lot of thread contention in our solution right now due to some lock-based caching logic that is hard to debug. It's not a deadlock: it eventually frees the lock and the process continues, but having a way to signal enter/exit of locks in telemetry would be very beneficial to us. And yes, I realize this is old. If your take has since changed, please let me know.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're looking for lock helpers. Jon Skeet's MiscUtil has some:
http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/usage/locking.html

The idea is that you replace your `lock` statements with `using` statements and thus preserve the try-finally structure:

```
class Example
{
    SyncLock padlock = new SyncLock();

    void Method1
    {
        using (padlock.Lock())
        {
            // Now own the padlock
        }
    }      

    void Method2
    {
        using (padlock.Lock())
        {
            // Now own the padlock
        }
    }
}
```

With regards to deadlock prevention, the library offers a specialized ordered lock:

```
class Example
{
    OrderedLock inner = new OrderedLock("Inner");
    OrderedLock outer = new OrderedLock("Outer");

    Example()
    {
        outer.InnerLock = inner;
    }
}
```

Of course, you could extend Jon's helpers, or simply create your own (for logging purposes, etc). Check out the link above for more information.

Comment: This still comes down to adapting all locks (and there are a lot of them), and next to that the writer admits that it's taking up performance because of the extra functionality. Performance is something to worry about in this project.

Comment: @Aidiakapi - So basically, you want more functionality, but you don't want it to reduce performance. Please let me know when you find out how to do this!

Comment: @Aidiakapi: I don't see a way around adapting all the existing locks. `Monitor` is a static class and thus implicitly sealed. Regarding performance, Jon addressed that: "Very few applications are likely to see a significant performance degredation due to using the locks, and I believe the benefits easily outweigh the slight performance loss [...] Unless you're acquiring at least a couple of hundred thousand locks per second, the performance difference made by using these locks is going to be lost in the noise."

Comment: No, I want functionality that I could temp. enable for debugging purposes, not while actually building it for release mode.

Comment: +1 - I really like the OrderedLock. That would nail deadlocking.

Answer (score 0):

That's a very bad idea. I never had to override Monitor.Enter / Exit or lock to overcome a deadlock. Please consider redesigning your code!
For example, use `ManualResetEvent` for the pulsing.

Comment: I'd appreciate it if you'd also say _why_ it is such a bad idea.

Comment: Like others and also myself already pointed out, you are going the wrong way in solving that deadlock. The problem lies within the structure of your code and the way locks are used and acquired. The right way would be, to analyze the situation, and change the code accordingly. We already provided some hints, that's all we can do, because we don't know your code.

Comment: As I've pointed out in other comments, the design is very well made, and it works perfectly, the deadlock was cause by a modification someone else made to a subclass.

Comment: Maybe, I misunderstood the reason why you want to override those methods. If it is just because you want to add the logging, it is not such a bad idea and ohadsc's answer may help you. I thought, you want to change the way those methods work, i.e. how they acquire and release the locks. You should clarify that in your question, so people don't get all crazy, like they do right now ;)

Comment: That's why I places this in the question: while keeping access to the base function to do the actual lock. I'm not intending to override the methods permanently only for temporarily logging of the locks. :)

Comment: Must have missed that one... :)